# While submitting app in Apple App Store, how to provide testing credentials?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Currently, I had done one application which supports only INDIA store only.
In this application 1st screen we keep it as Mobile number and then OTP will receive. If he eneter that valid OTP and then only we will allow him to see the other main functionality.

For this case, I have a doubt,
Today I am going to publish app in app store. How can I provide testing credentials to test apple development team?
Because, currently we are using dynamic OTP service gateway.

Can you suggest me, how could I resolve this issue.

Thansk

Comment: Another option is to record video of all features of application and provide link in review notes, then reviewer can see what inside

Answer (score 4):

When you submit, simply leave the test OTP and credentials in the the "App Review Information" section each time you release a new app version.
[image]

Comment: Means, we need to add one Mobile No & OTP for testing right?

Comment: Or only universal test OTP, we need to leave for testing @ajmccall

Comment: If you have a test number & OTC pair, I would add this to the release notes. The iTunes reviewers have encountered hundreds of different login processes and will be able to understand your review notes.

Comment: Does this help your question about iTunesConnect? Or are you asking the question "How can I add a a test OTC sign up process to my app?"

Comment: ThanQ @ajmccall, I am going to follow same and upload app in app store. I am giving up wote to you.